# What is an effective way to search for post-doc positions in physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

I am a graduate student in experimental physics, currently writing up my dissertation and beginning to apply to post-doc positions.  While it is very easy to find out about open positions in my particular sub-field (via various mailing lists), it is more difficult to find out about  potentially interesting positions in other sub-fields.

**What is a good way to identify potentially interesting post-doc position openings outside of one's sub-field?**

Comment: I have to point out that the place to begin should be your adviser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is a proper question to be answered with wiki.

### Resources For Job seeker

General:

- [Jobs for PhD](http://jobs.phds.org/)
- [Academic jobs](http://academicjobsonline.org/)

Physics:

- [SPIRES](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/jobs/)
- [American Physical Society (APS)](http://careers.aps.org/jobs/)

Astrophysics:

- [American Astronomical Society (AAS)](http://members.aas.org/JobReg/JobRegister.cfm)
- [European Astronomical Society (EAS)](http://eas.unige.ch/display_job.jsp)
- [European Space Agency (ESA)](http://www.esa.int/hr/vn.htm)
- [European Southern Observatory (ESO)](https://jobs.eso.org/)

Gravitational waves:

- [Gravitational wave detection jobs wiki](http://gwave.wikispot.org/Jobs)

Answer (score 6):

Talks, talks talks. If you're near graduation, you need as much publicity as possible.

**Give as many talks as possible**. Give talks at conferences, especially. Ask your advisor to have his friends invite you to give talks at other universities. Consider even cold-calling other physics research programs asking if they're looking for a speaker. During your talks, mention that you're graduating soon, and looking for a postdoc.

**Attend as many talks as possible**. Attend any talks by visitors that sound even halfway interesting. Go to conferences, and attend every session that sounds even halfway interesting. Corner as many interesting speakers as you can, and ask them if they're hiring.

**Don't be shy**. Most hiring is 'right place, right time', not 'perfect fit'.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in nuclear or particle physics or a related field you use [Job Search page on Spires](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/jobs/) (and not just for postdocs either).

And of course Physics Today and network like crazy. People who already know your work are likely to believe in you. People who know you adviser or current boss are also good marks.

Answer (score 4):

best site for astronomy/astrophysics:
[AAS](http://members.aas.org/JobReg/JobRegister.cfm)

and the famous [Rumor Mill](http://cdm.berkeley.edu/doku.php?id=astrophysicsjobs) about those jobs

Comment: Are the astrophysics rumor mills still active? Those in my field have really slowed down recently, which is too bad.

Comment: very much so, and in fact have improved in recent years, to include URL links to jobs in question

Answer (score 3):

In addition to searching for job postings, simply emailing research groups where you would like to work is surprisingly effective.  Even if they do not have an advertised opening, they might make one for you if they want to hire you.

Comment: Yeah, cold calling is incredibly effective. The earlier the better, because a lot of hiring is very sensitive to timing.

Answer (score 2):

This is where I found most of my opportunities:

http://tiptop.iop.org

Answer (score 0):

The monthly mag "Physics Today" has listings for openings for post docs. Ask your advisor for info. He/She should know what universities do research in your area of expertise.  Check the National Labs too.